# How to call function inside of the iframe? JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to call function that sits deep inside of the iframe. I was able to get down the path to my function but there is another problem. IFrame will load different url/page depends what user click on. So my path to the function will work if I'm on the page that is the parent of the function. If I'm on a different page this path won't work. Here is example:

```
parent.parent.document.getElementById('AppDisplay').contentWindow.userUnlock();
```

So I'm going two levels app to the main fram. Then I use `id` of the frame where my function is located. Inside of that frame is the page that hosts my function. I'm wondering if there is a way to get `url` of the document inside of the `iframe` AppDisplay?

```
<iframe name="AppDisplay" src="AppSign.cfm" id="AppDisplay" height="100%">
  #document
  //Here is my HTML & JS 
</iframe>
```

I need some way to check if I'm on the right page or if `userUnlock` function exist. If user is on a different page I shouldn't call function above.

Comment: You can check if a function is available like this: `if (.....contentWindow.userUnlock) ...` As for getting the url, that's the `.src` of the `iframe` element.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand it correctly , your frame and parent are pointing to different url. In that case, you won't be able to access anything because of the same-origin policy for security reasons.
Details here - [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: They are  on the same domain though, i.e. have the same origin.